# modifying object in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Below is my *app.js* for a freshly created react native app. I am trying to modify `lst` when mounting my component, mapping over it and changing the field `show`.

My expectation is that `componentDidMount` will execute synchronously, first logging the original list as shown:

```
[
        { show: false, src: 'pathtoimage1' },
        { show: false, src: 'pathtoimage2' }
      ]
```

Then, after `this.modifyList(lst)` is called, the next log statement should be this:

```
[
        { show: true, src: 'pathtoimage1' },
        { show: true, src: 'pathtoimage2' }
      ]
```

However, when I execute the code I get two identical log entries:

[image]

Clearly I'm missing some basic understanding here. Can someone explain what is going on, where to read more and how to achieve my goal?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  modifyList = (mylist) => {
    mylist.map((obj, idx) => {
      mylist[idx].show = true;
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const lst = [
        { show: false, src: 'pathtoimage1' },
        { show: false, src: 'pathtoimage2' }
      ]
    console.log("before function", lst);
    this.modifyList(lst);
    console.log("after function", lst);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to this MWE</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nit: change your `map` to a `forEach`, or better, properly use map: `mylist = mylist.map((obj) => {
      obj.show = true;
      return obj;
    });`

Comment: in your question you state that the debugger shows both items as `show: true` is that not your expectation?

Comment: What do you get if you pass `JSON.stringify(lst)` into the console log?